# How to create a date time offset column that defaults to the current utc date time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, utc

I want to create a table with a `CreatedOn` column, of type `DateTimeOffset`, and when a record is inserted, I want the current UTC date and time to be used.

If I add a default constraint of `GETUTCDATE()`, it puts in the local time with a 0 offset. If I use `SYSUTCDATETIME()` it puts in the local time with the correct offset.

Is it possible to get the utc time in with a 0 offset?

Comment: Can you provide some results on what `GETUTCDATE(), SYSUTCDATETIME(), SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()` are returning for you and what the correct offset should be for you? I'm confused as to why you don't use `SYSUTCDATETIME()` if it's giving you the correct offset. I read your question a few times and am at a loss--maybe the sys DT isn't set correctly?

Comment: My current local time is 2016-08-24 13:44:19.5187024, select  SysUtcDateTime() returns 2016-08-24 20:44:19.5187024. That is the correct utc date and time, which is offset 0 even though it doesn't say. If I set my default constraint to SysUtcDateTime(), the value in the column is 2016-08-24 13:44:19.5187024 +00:00. It gives me a local time with an invalid offset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you could just force it to what ever offset you want depending on what the `SYSUTCDATETIME()` or any other date time stamp is. You can use the below and change the offset to what ever you want it to be and use `GETDATE()` instead of `GETUTCDATE()`, etc...

```
SELECT GETUTCDATE() AS UTC_DT, SYSUTCDATETIME() AS SYS_UTC_DT, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AS SYS_DT_OFFSET

SELECT CAST(TODATETIMEOFFSET(GETUTCDATE(), '+00:00') AS DATETIME2) AS UTC_WITH_OFFSET   --SQL SERVER 2008 and onward...
SELECT GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'                                                     --SQL SERVER 2016 only...
```

Comment: This is close enough to what we're going to have to do. The default we'll use is SYSDATETIMEOFFSET and live with all of our dates having our local offset.

Comment: Still an interesting problem that i'm going to investigate @JoshuaBelden